# Execution failed for task ':openCVLibrary310:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: java, android, opencv

My build.gradle (app) looks like this. I am using opencV310 Library

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "indidoc.pdf.converter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1'
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jni/'] } }
    sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs', 'src/main/jniLibs']
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    defaultConfig{
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary310')
    implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.mthli:Knife:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    implementation 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ctodobom:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.4.ctodobom.sections'
    implementation 'com.github.nostra13:Android-Universal-Image-Loader:v1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.ctodobom:FabToolbar:3c5f0e0ff1b6d5089e20b7da7157a604075ae943'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'it.chengdazhi.styleimageview:styleimageview:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.10.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation('com.github.thekhaeng:pushdown-anim-click:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
}
```

The Error I am getting while building is

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\framework.aidl

I am getting this error while debugging. Please put your suggestions where I am doing wrong. I have already me=ade some changes in build.gradle but it doesn't help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add openCV Library into your android studio project before implementing in build gradle. I think this link will help you understand. [Integrating Your Android App with OpenCV Library](https://medium.com/easyread/integrating-your-android-app-with-opencv-library-266b2ea913d3)

Comment: Did you try every steps discussed on the document link?

Comment: Yes @pushpo I have followed every steps. Still it didn't work for me.

Comment: @AMITKUMAR I couldn't find your buildToolsVersion in gradle file. It should be like buildToolsVersion "29.0.2" . Try that.

Comment: Yes I tried that already but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: UPDATE :  I ran the same code on different PC and then ran on my PC, the problem was solved. I don't know what was missing when I first executed it on my PC.

Comment: Sometimes there would be cache issues. But thank God it fixed.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works for me as well. Im using mac m1. Hope this will help you as well.

Here are the steps I followed

softwareupdate --install-rosetta

And

~/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/cmake --version

Make sure your command with cmake and the corresponding version does not throw an error.

https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1283#issuecomment-1380368472

Comment: Buwaneka Sumanasekara, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)